# ValueError: Geometry column cannot contain mutiple geometry types when writing to file

Tags: python, geopandas

I have this list:

`shapefiles` that has these directories for the files: (pairs of pst and dbound) in each folder.

```
[['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\eff\\20194\\DBOUND\\DBOUND.shp',
  'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\eff\\20194\\PST\\PST.shp'],
 ['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\eff\\20042\\DBOUND\\DBOUND.shp',
  'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\eff\\20042\\PST\\PST.shp'],
 ['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\eff\\20161\\DBOUND\\DBOUND.shp',
  'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\eff\\20161\\PST\\PST.shp'],
 ['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\eff\\20029\\DBOUND\\DBOUND.shp',
  'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\eff\\20029\\PST\\PST.shp'],
 ['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\eff\\20008\\DBOUND\\DBOUND.shp',
  'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\eff\\20008\\PST\\PST.shp']]
```

When I try this to export the `shp` returns:

> ValueError: Geometry column cannot contain mutiple geometry types
>   when writing to file.

```
import geopandas
for i in shapefiles:
    pst = gpd.read_file(i[0])
    dbound = gpd.read_file(i[1])
    dbound.reset_index(inplace=True)
    wdp = gpd.sjoin(pst, dbound, how="inner", op='within')
    wdp['DEC_ID']=wdp['index']

    folder=i[0].split("\\")[-3]
    o = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\yyyyyh\wdp_'+folder
    wdp.to_file(o)
```

but when I try it manually (without the loop) it works perfect. So how these geometry types are a problem only with the loop. I literally tried the same shapefiles and all fine.

Comment: Shouldnt you have a file ending: `o = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\yyyyyh\wdp_'+folder+'.shp'` or is shape default?

Comment: It gets it automatically.

Comment: It's strange but I did what the answer suggested and it didn't work caused this error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`.at the geom assigning

Comment: The problem was the position of the i[0] and i[1].They had to be checked with the position of the files that were communicating in their folder and sync. Just switch the 0 and 1.Everything is good.